# R: Filling out dataframe to create symmetric identity plot

Tags: r, heatmap

I have some calculations that are written to a file and read into a dataframe that is arranged as follows:

```
sequence_1  sequence_2  identity
CP010953    CP010953    100
CP010953    CP012689    73.9
CP010953    CP000025    73.86
CP010953    CP012149    73.77
CP010953    HE978252    73.72999999999999
CP010953    CP009043    83.35000000000001
```

The data comes from a calculation (in Python) that calculates the number of character matches between two strings divided by the length of one of the strings (both strings will have the same length). It seemed like a good idea at the time, but when I did the calculations, I used the itertools.combinations_with_replacement command to make the calculations quicker. So, if I am comparing 3 strings (a,b,c), it will only compare a&b, a&c, b&c, and not b&a, c&a, and c&b since they will respectively have the same values as a&b, a&c, and b&c. The problem is that when I read the data into R and plot the heatmap, I end up with this:

[image]

That is a bunch of gaps (you may be able to see that the values I need are all there -- example: AL111168 and CP000538 (both located on the lower left hand side) have the value on the y axis, but not the x axis)!

Is there a way to fill in those gaps with the appropriate values in R? I could do this in a loop, but that is not very R-esque. I am certain this has been asked before, but I don't think I am using the right search terms.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

file_name <- args[1]
gene_name <- args[2]

image_name = paste(gene_name, '.png', sep='')

myDF <- read.csv(file_name, header=T, sep='\t')   

my_palette <- colorRampPalette(c('red', 'yellow', 'green'))

png(filename=image_name, width=3750,height=2750,res=300)
par(mar=c(9.5,4.3,4,2))
print(corpus <- qplot(x=sequence_1, y=sequence_2, data=myDF, fill=identity, geom='tile') +

                    geom_text(aes(label=identity), color='black', size=3) + 
                    scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(0, 100), low='gold', high='green4') +
                    labs(title='Campylobacter Pair-wise Sequence Identity Comparison', x=NULL, y=NULL) +
                    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = 'Sequence\nSimilarity %', title.theme = element_text(size=15, angle = 0))) + theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12))  +
                    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, size=14, hjust=1, colour='black'), axis.text.y=element_text(size=14, hjust=1, colour='black')) )
dev.off()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I figured out a way to do it.

```
mDF <- myDF
colnames(mDF)[1] <- 'sequence_2'
colnames(mDF)[2] <- 'sequence_1'
newDF <- rbind(mDF, myDF)
```

Then plot newDF.